# HTML Ref Tag - is this a thing?

Tags: html

I'm sure I'm about to feel absolutely stupid, but isn't there supposed to be a 'ref' tag?  I can't find information about it anywhere.  What I'm looking for is a tag to use when citing/referencing material from external sources such as Wikipedia.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is vague, and from the comment, it seems that the *intended* question was something completely different (namely, about quotations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does exist.  However, it's called `<cite>`.

An example [usage from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite):

```
More information can be found in <cite>[ISO-0000]</cite>
```

Comment: Isn't that for the title of the place you are citing from, though?  I'm looking for something to put around the actual block of text that was extracted from the source.

Comment: you mean `<blockquote>`?

Comment: Now, any consistent cross-browser way to reset all the css for blockquote?

Comment: The defined meaning of `cite` varies by HTML version. The only verified real effect is that it causes its content to be rendered in italic by default.

Comment: @jpppp Yes that is correct.  I thought that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The <ref > tag in wikipedia looks like HTML code, but it is a tag specific to Wikipedia. See [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Footnotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Footnotes#Footnotes:_the_basics)